# Why this 'syntax error' before 'else'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, size, unzip

I'm writing a shell script to unzip files in a directory. There are files with same name in different zip files; the code must keep the bigger one.

I need to unzip files in /test directory. There are thousands of zip files and I don't have room to unzip them at the same time. So I create a folder /test/tmp and unzip one zip file into the folder. Then compare the file in the /test and /test/tmp folders. If there are duplicate file, compare their size and keep the file with bigger size in the /test. If there isn't duplicate, move the file from /test/tmp to /tmp.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
A="/test"
B="/test/tmp"
archives=$(ls $A *.zip 2>/dev/null)
for archive in "${archives}"  
do
    mkdir -p "${B}" && unzip "${archive}" -d $B
    for file_tmp in 'ls $B *.log 2>/dev/null'
    do
        file_root="${A}${file_tmp}"
        if [-f "${file_root}"] then
            if [[$(stat -c %s "${file_tmp}") -ge $(stat -c %s "${file_root}")]]
            then mv "${file_tmp}" "${file_root}"
            else rm "${file_tmp}"
            fi 
        else mv "${file_tmp}" $A
        fi
    done
done
```

But I keep getting the error

```
unziptest.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
unziptest.sh: line 16: `            else mv "${file_tmp}" $A'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use a single line, then:

```
if [-f "${file_root}"] then
```

must have a semicolon before the `then`:

```
if [ -f "${file_root}" ]; then
```

You also need the spaces around the command name `[`, and a space before the final argument `]` of the `[` command.  If you use the `[[` notation, then spacing is less critical.

Comment: I change those place and my code run now. But I cannot get the result I want. Can you help me to make working?

Comment: What does 'cannot get the result I want' mean?  It is so imprecise as to be impossible to answer.  I recommend stepping through the code by running `sh -x yourscript` and seeing what it does, and where it goes wrong.  I'd make sure I get to see every intermediate value, too.  For example, I'd probably capture the output of the two `stat -c` commands into variables, and then compare the variables.

Comment: Separately from all that, the line `for file_tmp in 'ls $B *.log 2>/dev/null'` does not run the `ls` command because you have single quotes instead of back quotes or `$(...)`.  You need: `for file_tmp in $(ls $B *.log 2>/dev/null)`.  But there are still problems; you get the contents of directory `$B` (without any pathname), and you get all the log files in the current directory.  That's probably not what you had in mind; maybe you need a slash: `for file_tmp in $(ls $B/*.log 2>/dev/null)`.  You'd notice this if you ran with `sh -x`.

Comment: It seems shell has file variable and file name variable. I can unzip each file to the directory by 'for archive in *.zip
do
 unzip  -d $B "./$archive"
done'. rather than 'archives=$(ls $A *.zip 2>/dev/null)
for archive in "${archives}"  
do
    mkdir -p "${B}" && unzip "${archive}" -d $B'.  I follow all those sample code from internet and composite this code.. Each query works fine seperately. But I cannot achieve my target with whole script.

Comment: Found the mistake, I misuse '' as ``, there are so many tricks in shell~~~~ lol

Answer (score 0):

Change  `if [-f "${file_root}"] then`

to

```
if [-f "${file_root}"]
then
```

or

```
if [-f "${file_root}"] ; then
```

Comment: Thanks, I change those place and code run now. But it cannot unzip files at all. I'm a newbie to Shell/bash. Can you help me to make the code work? I need to handle zip file name with space.

Comment: Note that your change is necessary; it is not, however, sufficient.  Few systems have a command called `[-f`; you need a space between the `[` and the `-f` to invoke the `[` (aka `test`) command (it usually exists as either `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[` or both).  The last argument to `[` must be `]` on its own, so you need a space there, too.